# Python file readline issue with multiple linefeed

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, readline

I'm trying to parse a large file line by line. However, when I run this program :

```
def main():
    fd_in = open('file1.txt')
    ctr = 0

    while True:
        line = fd_in.readline().strip()
        if not line:
            break

        print(line)

        ctr += 1
        if ctr % 1000000 == 0:
            print(ctr)

    print(fd_in.tell())
    fd_in.close()
```

It stops before reading all the file.

```
[...]
495448578 # tell result
```

If I hexdump 8 bytes before the wrong end of the file I get :

```
hexdump -C -s 495448570 -n 10 file1.txt
1d87f1fa  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a 0d 0a 68                    |hello....h|
```

So readline should return a line feed instead of an empty string.

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `line` is just whitespace, the `strip()` will turn `line` into an empty string, triggering that `break`. Strip after you check for eof.

```py
def main():
    fd_in = open('file1.txt')
    ctr = 0

    while True:
        line = fd_in.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.strip()

        print(line)

        ctr += 1
        if ctr % 1000000 == 0:
            print(ctr)

    print(fd_in.tell())
    fd_in.close()
```

Comment: I completely missed that. My bad, thanks for your quick reply !